# How to hide content and show the rest by scrolling

Tags: php, javascript, html, scroll

I have this project: [image]

And i want the content scrolls inside the grey box. Not go under the box or get out of the box.

How can i do this?

Comment: Can you share a jsFiddle?

Comment: Have you set up overflow: hidden for the grey box ?

Comment: maybe you also have a look at this: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need CSS to limit the height of your grey box, and say the rest of the content (incase it's higher than the hight you gave) is scrollable:

```
#grey_box {
height:300px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

In this code I assumed your grey box was a div with `id="grey_box"` and height 200px. Change those values if it's not correct. The important is to give a height to the div, and overflow:scroll;